# jQuery: Select a href containing colon

Tags: jquery

My anchor links should be animated, so that they do not jump immediate to the link but rather scroll in a smooth fashion. 
This should work in both directions, i.e. when clicking on the link containing the `footnote` and the `reversefootnote` class.

### Structure

HTML

```
<p>
  Some text.
  <a href="#fn:1" id="fnref:1" title="see footnote" class="footnote">[1]</a>
</p>

<div class="footnotes">
  <ol>
    <li id="fn:1">
      <p>
        A footnote.
        <a href="#fnref:1" title="return to article" class="reversefootnote">&nbsp;?</a>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("a[href*='#fn\\:']").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var $el = $(href);

    $("html, body").animate({"scrollTop": $el.offset().top}, 500);
});
```

### Problem

The problem that it does not work occurs only when I use a colon in `href`, therefore I would be more than happy if someone can show me a way how to escape these, or even show me a better approach.

Comment: Do your hrefs need to have a colon? Can't you use some other character?

Comment: You are using quotation  marks and there is no need to escape the character http://jsfiddle.net/6wwHQ/

Comment: Can't you just select by the `footnote`/`reversefootnote` classes?

Comment: I use MultiMarkdown which renders that way, so unless I edit the code they should be considered as given.

Comment: @undefined Can you post a working fiddle, where smooth scrolling is active and where there are more than one footnote in the text - as this usually is the case - so that we need to select abstractly and not absolute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to escape the colon in that pattern match....

but the colon should be escaped in the selector:

```
var $el = $(href.replace(':', '\\:'));
```

and the first selector should be altered:

```
$("a[href*='#fn\\:']").click(function(event) {...});
```